# Can we set default values for inputs on demand in your workflow file set for Github Issue

Tags: powershell, github-actions, github-api, default-value, github-issues

Below is my github actions ISSUE_TEMPLATE that seeks input from user.

```
name: GH Action details

description: GH Issue form

title: "GH Action details"

assignees:

  - my-devops

labels:

  - "gh inventory"

body:

  - type: markdown

    attributes:

      value: |

        ### Want to add?

       

        ---

       

        Please fill out the information below 

  - type: input

    id: repository-name

    attributes:

      label: Repository Name

      description: Provide the name of the repository

    validations:

      required: true
```

Below is how the issue form looks before and after user comments.

[image]

Desired output where the user input is read and displayed.
[image]

I wish to submit a similar issue comment using PowerShell. Tried the below [You can try to run on your system using ISE, powershell]: Powershell code below:

```
$Token = "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"
$RepoOwner = "knowyrtech"
$RepoName = "mongomaskwinvslinux"

 

$IssueTitle = "GH Action Onboard inventory details"

 

# Create a hashtable for the input values
$inputValues = @{
    "ref" = "main"
    "inputs" = @{
        "repository-name" = "YourRepositoryName"
    }
}

# Convert the hashtable to JSON
$inputJson = $inputValues | ConvertTo-Json


 
$ApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/$RepoOwner/$RepoName/issues"

$IssueData = @{
    title = $IssueTitle
    body  = $inputJson
} | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiUrl -Method Post -Headers @{
    "Authorization" = "token $Token"
    "Accept"        = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $IssueData


$response
```

Running this creates a comment but not as desired output snapshot shared above.

I also tried

```
$inputValues = @{
    "ref" = "main"
    "inputs" = @{
        "repository-name" = @{
            "default" = 'wowo'
        }
    }
}


$inputJson = $inputValues | ConvertTo-Json
```

However, unable to comment as inputs as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you are creating a JSON object representing what seems to be inputs for an action workflow and used that JSON object directly as the body of the GitHub issue:

```
$inputValues = @{
    "ref" = "main"
    "inputs" = @{
        "repository-name" = "YourRepositoryName"
    }
}
$inputJson = $inputValues | ConvertTo-Json
...
$IssueData = @{
    title = $IssueTitle
    body  = $inputJson
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Since [GitHub issues created through the API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-issue) do not natively support the direct population of issue form fields in this manner. [GitHub Issue Forms](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#creating-issue-forms) and the GitHub API work separately; the API does not provide functionality to populate Issue Forms fields directly.

Instead of trying to use a JSON object to represent the issue body, you can try and use a Markdown formatted string to represent the issue body, which includes the default values you want to include in a structured manner that visually resembles your GitHub Issue Form:

```
$IssueBody = @"
### Want to add?

---

Please fill out the information below 

**Repository Name**
$RepositoryName
"@
...
$IssueData = @{
    title = $IssueTitle
    body  = $IssueBody
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

The `$IssueBody` variable contains a string with Markdown formatting, which structures the information similarly to your GitHub Issue Form when viewed on the GitHub platform.

Full script:

```
$Token = "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"
$RepoOwner = "knowyrtech"
$RepoName = "mongomaskwinvslinux"

$IssueTitle = "GH Action Onboard inventory details"

# Define the repository name (or any other values you want to set as default)
$RepositoryName = "YourRepositoryName"

# Create a Markdown formatted string that represents the issue body
$IssueBody = @"
### Want to add?

---

Please fill out the information below 

**Repository Name**
$RepositoryName
"@

$ApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/$RepoOwner/$RepoName/issues"

$IssueData = @{
    title = $IssueTitle
    body  = $IssueBody
} | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiUrl -Method Post -Headers @{
    "Authorization" = "token $Token"
    "Accept"        = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $IssueData

$response
```